# Regularity of the heat equation: Neumann boundary conditions

Tags: parabolic-pde, regularity, heat-equation

I am looking for references to regularity estimates for the solution of a heat equation with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions on $[0,T]\times D$ for some smooth domain $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ and $T>0$, i.e.

$$
\partial_t u -\Delta u =f,\quad u(0)=0,\quad \partial_n u|_{[0,T]\times \partial D}=0.
$$

I would like to have something like $\|u\|(m)\lesssim \|f\|(m-1)$, where

$$\|u\|(m):=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\|\partial_t^k u\|_{L^2([0,T],H^{2m-2k}(D))}$$

(Sorry for some reasons the subscripts work only sporadically, so $\|u\|_m:=\|u\|(m)$)

Evan's PDE book treats only Dirichlet boundary conditions (where this result holds under some restrictions). Is there anything for periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: As for as I can see, the computation leading up to (39) also works in under Neumann boundary condition.

Comment: See the book of Gilkey (Invariance theory, the heat equation and the Atiyah Singer Index theorem) where general elliptic boundary conditons are treated. The parabolic theory follows from the elliptic theory once you know that the Laplace eigenfunctions are smooth up to the boundary (plus suitable estimates).